# Get incoming caller ID from TAPI in C# Winform App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tapi

I am trying to write a Winform / C# app which will grab the CLID of the incoming call and then allow me to do a lookup in my database (it's for a CRM system).

I have been using the JulMar Atapi library which works fine for outgoing calls, but seems to refuse to to even recognise an incoming call at all.

I have the following code when initiating to try and get the line to be monitored / listened to, but when an incoming call is made it never fires CallInfo or CallState changed events :

```
if (_atapiMgr.Initialize())
{
    foreach (TapiLine line in _atapiMgr.Lines)
    {
        line.NewCall += this.OnNewCall;
        line.CallInfoChanged += this.OnCallInfoChange;
        line.CallStateChanged += this.OnCallStateChange;
        line.Changed += this.OnLineStateChanged;
        line.Ringing += this.OnRinging;
        line.Monitor();
    }
}
```

We use Avaya Phonemanager which does display the CLID when in use. Are there any alternative TAPI .Net wrappers, or do I need to look at working with TAPI directly to get this to work?

Comment: Use a test tool like phone.exe to check if the problem is in the lib or the driver (https://helpdesk.estos.de/Knowledgebase/Article/View/82/3/howto-ephoneexe--tapi-test-tool) (English: https://www.google.be/search?q=m%2Ftranslate%3Fsl%3Dauto%26tl%3Den%26js%3Dy%26prev%3D_t%26hl%3Den%26ie%3DUTF-8%26u%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fhelpdesk.estos.de%252FKnowledgebase%252FArt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=5Ou9WvI7hsGAB_XkiJAH)

Comment: Hi - that doesn't seem to work for incoming calls either so does that suggest the TAPI driver?

Comment: It does suggest your application is not the problem (yet). Make sure your TAPI is enabled and licensed in your PBX. That your extension is configured to be included TAPI monitor (driver or PBX). You may want to contact your supplier for this as it varies from vendor to vendor how you go about debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on TAPI (who is?) but I've just started using the .Net wrapper for TAPI 3.0 from Jalmar (https://github.com/markjulmar/itapi3). I've found the easiest way to add event handlers is to add the dll (ITapi3.dll) to the VS tool box (drag it there) and then add it to your project by dragging it from the toolbox onto the design view tab of your form. Then when you click on the dll in the lower part of the form view you can see the events available in the properties window. Double click on an even and it will add a handler to your code.